# performance issues - is it the database?

Tags: database, mysql, performance

I'm experiencing pages loading very slowly, it's happening intermittently on a low traffic EE site. Most of the traffic is just me.

When they load slow, they take a good 30 seconds or so.

But when the load fast they are very quick. Less than a second.

The template debugger and output profiler numbers look good as far as I can tell.

Could this be due to mysql table locking?

---

updates:

For future reference, I upgraded MySQL to MariaDB (a drop-in MySQL replacement) on the host and also changed DB tables from the default MyISAM to InnoDB (actually XtraDB) and have continued to watch it. These changes have had a positive impact on performance so far.

Comment: What host are you on? What type? I've worked on shared servers (GoDaddy, Dreamhost) that stack tons of users on a single server. If one site on that server gets slammed with traffic they are all affected. I've found moving to a more reputable (and usually more expensive) shared host is a night and day difference. We are talking 30second load times vs. 1.5seconds with no other change than the host or server type.

Comment: Do you have new version check enabled or devot:ee monitor installed? I've seen both of these massively slow down sites when not functioning correctly.

Comment: @DanJohnson I'm on a dedicated Hybrid VPS at Wired Tree. Usage overall isn't very heavy.

Comment: @PhilipZaengle neither should be in use. I have new version check turned off in my config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've hosted one project on a Wired tree VPS and had similar issues. I think they changed how PHP was setup on the server for me which got things running better. Best to contact them directly. They'll know what to do. I doubt it's an EE issue.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, are you still with wiredtree now?

Comment: The site is still hosted there but I do very little work on it now. It was sluggish in development. I called several times about it and they made setting changes on the server if I remember.

Comment: Question: Are you seeing sluggishness in the CP and the frontend of the site or only on frontend? Have you run a tracert while the sluggishness is happening? Does the Network tab in FireBug reveal anything?

Comment: Sluggish in both places, but intermittently. I haven't tried a tracert or looked at the network tab much.

Comment: I think it's the PHP and recommend submitting a ticket with Wired Tree or moving to EngineHosting.

Comment: I'll see what I can find out with support. Do you recall by chance what changes they made to php?

Comment: They changed the way PHP ran on the server if I remember correctly.

Comment: I'll look into it with the host further. Thanks for the advice.